# What sort of things might cause a OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: wpf, telerik, out-of-memory

I'm facing issue with outofmemoryexception, with error message caught by App_DispatcherUnhandledException (1 of some error messages):

```
Message: Zgłoszono wyjątek typu 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. Source: PresentationFramework 

StackTrace:   
 w System.Windows.TreeChangeInfo.CreateParentInheritableProperties(DependencyObject d, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   w System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   w System.Windows.Media.Visual.FireOnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
   w System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual child)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_TemplateChild(UIElement value)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.WireRootObjectToParent(Object createdObject, DependencyObject rootObject, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(Object createdObject, DependencyObject& rootObject, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass45_0.<LoadOptimizedTemplateContent>b__2(Object sender, XamlObjectEventArgs args)
   w System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnBeforeProperties(Object value)
   w System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   w System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
   w System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   w System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCellsPanel.MeasureCell(IColumnElement column, GridViewCellBase cell, Size size)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCellsPanel.RealizeAndMeasureCells(Int32 startIndex, Int32 predictedLastIndex, Func`2 calculateLastIndex)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCellsPanel.UpdateVirtualizedCells()
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRowItem.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewVirtualizingPanel.FlatLayoutStrategy.RealizeRows(Int32 startIndex, Int32 endIndex, Double& verticalOffset, HashSet`1& realizedRows)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewVirtualizingPanel.FlatLayoutStrategy.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewVirtualizingPanel.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewDataControl.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   w System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   w System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   w System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   w System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   w System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   w System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   w System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   w System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   w System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   w System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

HResult: -2147024882
```

Here are some informations:

- Application runs on RDS, with 15-25 users using application
- Available memory: 32 GB
- Avg useed memory: 17 GB
- There is never a situation, when used memory hits 30 GB (highest peak was around 23 GB)
- CPU is fine, avg 40%, peaks to 60% used
- RAM usage per app instance grows with usage to, around 1.5 GB per instance.
- App was profiled multiple times, there are 0 memory leaks, according to VS Profiler, and other profilers (including JetBrains one)
- App uses Telerik libraries
- App uses Entity Framework

I'm stuck and have no idea where to look for potential issues. Optimization took me weeks and it went pretty well - I've managed to fix typical memory leaks and memory distribution issues, sometimes app needs to launch GC.Collect() manually, but it happens rarely. There is also no pattern, when OutOfMemoryException hits, leaving me with no clue, where to look for an issue.

Last thing, in my opinion the application is too big for WPF, due to classic WPF memory growth (app goes from 60K to 1.5k of ram usage in span of couple hours), but I have no choice other, than fixing this issue.

### Edit

I'm not an admin on RDS environment, there is another engineer doing deployment and administration, maybe there is some kind of changes he possibly made, that started to cause this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler (for example like JetBrains dotMemory) to find out if there are any leaks, and if so where they're coming from? I don't think that WPF it self is the issue here, I've seen WPF used sucessfully in some quite large applications with no problems, and I've never heard of nor experienced any kind of _"classic WPF memory growth"_.

Comment: Too big for WPF? What does that even mean? Out of memory is happening because allocated memory for the applications process 2 GB if I remember correctly is used up. You say: you have done some optimisation, look there first. Other than that, the issue is usually within using `Name` or `x:Name` etc

Comment: Here is a link [Jet Brains article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/). Is there any reason why Telerik is being used?

Comment: @bassfader Read my post carefully plz, I've answered your first question

Comment: @XAMlMAX I can't really optimize it further (afaik), it took literally weeks of hard work to do profilling and code optimalization. And well, it worked for this part. I'm familiar with jet brains article and yes, there are plenty of reasons why Telerik is being used.

Comment: I meant look at the code that you created when you were optimising, did the exception occur before your optimisation? I don't see any MvvM tag on the question so I am assuming there isn't any, and this would lead me to advise you to adapt the app to use MvvM, code behind and event handlers are a thing of a past, use Commands, DataTemplates to make the app tick. I am guessing there is a lingering reference to a window that is being created over and over again. You wouldn't have that with DataTemplates and MvvM, if used correctly that is.

Comment: There's a bunch of measuring going on there. You could make the columns fixed width and maybe avoid that. Avoid going over the available width with colums. Check your gridview is definitely virtualising. Reduce height of the gridview so less rows are presented. Consider experimenting with the recycling. Filter data before presenting so you minimise the rows presented.

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard to figure out the exact cause like this but I can suggest some troubleshooting mechanisms.

1. Your stack trace suggests you are using a Telerik gridview. Try commenting it out or replacing with a normal gridview and see if the exception still comes. That way at least you can be sure which element is the culprit. Once you confirm which element is causing the issue, try creating a custom control by inheriting from the same type. Then in all the methods add logs call the base method. This way you will not lose the functionality at the same time can confirm what's going wrong.
2. Check if your running into some kind of infinite loop. The call-stack suggests that when it is trying to render all your elements it is running out of memory. This can come if there is some kind of ItemSource involved which is way too huge or so cyclic dependent controls are used.

Comment: 1. Can't do this. App is running on RDS production enviroment, and error occurs randomly accros the app (according to users). It have never happened on my test enviroment (tested it locally and on my RDS)
2. During optimalization process, I've eliminated long loops...

Comment: 1. In that case create the custom control and create the package with that. Next time the error comes those logs may help you to navigate in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

"There are 0 memory leaks" is a strong statement. Memory leaks typically reveal in very specific scenarios, so you should profile each possible workflow to state that - and this is impractical/impossible for larger apps. So the best thing you can do is probably to interview the users about their usage patterns and try to reproduce the leak locally with a profiler attached.

Also, investigating the call stack for the `OutOfMemoryException` is not always useful, as *any* allocation could cause it if there is not enough memory (so Telerik are maybe not to blame, though you can check their feedback portal for public issues mentioning [memory](https://feedback.telerik.com/wpf/search?listMode=Search&categoryId=602&statusId=4&searchTerm=memory) or [OutOfMemoryException](https://feedback.telerik.com/wpf/search?listMode=Search&categoryId=602&statusId=4&searchTerm=OutOfMemoryException).

Otherwise, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133254/outofmemoryexception-ideas-from-your-experience#comment102654087_58133254) in the comments, most of the good profilers detect common memory leaks, and even common WPF memory leaks, but, again, you have to run the app *through the specific scenario* (e.g. open and close a specific window), take the snapshots, and investigate the profiler suggestions.

Last, by default WPF app run as an x86 process, giving them practically maximum of ~2GB of memory. Of course, there are class of apps that just need more memory (e.g. working with huge text streams in memory), if this is your case, you can try switching the app to x64 process, which will allow much more (16TB? if I remember) memory. Just have in mind that this could increase your memory even more (as simple types now [use twice more memory](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx)) and could potentially slow down your application. Running x64 apps with the debugger attached also have [some caveats](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Dec/19/Visual-Studio-Debugging-and-64-Bit-NET-Applications).

Comment: Moving to x64 might actually help, maybe I'll give it a shot. On the other hand, memory growth is much quicker, when I build it on x64.